# Primitive array sorting using comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I am solving the following problem and trying to find better and cleaner way of sorting.

**Questions** 
1. I just realized that Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator) won't work with int[] arr. I need to convert to Integer[] to sort. Is there any other way to sort int[] directly?
2. Is there a better way of writing this program?

reference: https://www.pramp.com/challenge/4E4NW7NjbnHQEx1AxoXE

Absolute Value Sort
Given an array of integers arr, write a function absSort(arr), that sorts the array according to the absolute values of the numbers in arr. If two numbers have the same absolute value, sort them according to sign, where the negative numbers come before the positive numbers.

Examples:

input:  arr = [2, -7, -2, -2, 0]
output: [0, -2, -2, 2, -7]

My solution

```
static int[] absSortArray(int[] arr) {

        Integer[] input = new Integer[arr.length];
        for (int i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = arr[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(input, (a, b) -> ((Math.abs(a) == Math.abs(b)) ? ((a < b) ? -1 : 1) : (Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(b)) ? -1 : 1));

        int[] output =  new int[input.length];
        for (int i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own array sort.  One nice approach is to consider the original array to be a list of N sorted lists of 1, so copy it to a new array sorted as follows: merge the first two lists into a sorted list of 2, merger the second two lists into a sorted list of 2, merge those lists into a sorted list of 4, repeat for 4 new lists, merge to sorted list of 8, etc.  You can use the zero bits in the current element count to tell you when to merge how many.  It has the advantage of being very multi level cache, RAM, VM friendly, as it works with small sets first, doubling set size with each pass, returning to recent values of ascending age.

Another favorite is to move your data to an ordered list: tree, trie, skip list.  Even C had a tree: tsearch().  If the available tools require an object or struct, make a simple one.  Sometimes people look for code solutions when there are data solutions.  This is especially nice if the input arrival is gradual, a sort that occurs with each add and is ready for output the instant the last item is added.

For small lists, I have no problem with an insert sort or a bubble sort n^2/2.

If values are not unique, a class/struct with value and count makes them unique and more compact.